# How can I watch videos from the BBC web site on a device with an ARMv6 processor?

Tags: video, armv6

The BBC web site has many pages with videos, e.g. http://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/technology/article/art20150206154333467

On Android, the page prompts me to install the "BBC Media Player" app, but unfortunately this app requires an ARMv7 processor, but I have ARMv6.

Are there any other ways of persuading these videos to play?

Answer (score 1):

According to BBC's site: "Your device needs to run Android 2.2 (or higher) and have a minimum ARMv7 processor" to *play* programmes (*download* requires 4.0+).

reference: http://iplayerhelp.external.bbc.co.uk/tv/android_iplayerapp

Comment: Ah, so my problem isn't android version, it's processor: I'm on ARMv6.  Updating my question to reflect this.